# vee-validate Custom validation rules not working

Tags: vuejs2, custom-validators

#### Versions:

- VueJs: 2.2.6
- Vee-Validate: ^2.0.0-beta.25

#### Description:

I am working on a project, where I use [laravel-vue-starter](https://github.com/g0ld3lux/laravel-vue-starter)
as a base template.

I wants to use a custom validation for password. So I created a resources\assets\js\validators\passwordValidators.js file with code:

```
import { Validator } from 'vee-validate';

Validator.extend('password', {
    getMessage: field => 'Insert a strong password, it should contain Uppercase letter, lowercase letter, number and special character',
    validate: value => /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.[\W]).{8,}$/.test(value)
});
```

But when I am adding`v-validate="'password'"`
It produce an error`[vee-validate] No such validator 'password' exists`

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer is simple, you are now using a rule name 'password' , but your rule is password.

So try this in your markup (string notation), remove the single quotes.

```
v-validate = "password"
```

Or you can also use the object notation when you have more then 1 and complex rules.

```
v-validate = "{password: true}"
```

Regards Ben